# Boolean value return from Neo4j cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this query for returning the `hashTag name`, `hashTag count` and if it has the `Featured` label return `true`. `HashTag` node just has a `tag` property`.  It's working :

```
MATCH (:RateableEntity)<-[:TAG]-(hashtag:HashTag:Featured)
WITH hashtag,
  (CASE WHEN 'Featured' IN LABELS(hashtag) THEN true ELSE false END) AS HASHTAG_FEATURED_LABEL
RETURN hashtag.tag As HASHTAG_NAME, 
  COUNT(hashtag) as HASHTAG_FREQUENTLY,
  HASHTAG_FEATURED_LABEL
ORDER BY HASHTAG_NAME ASC 
SKIP 0
LIMIT 20
```

But I'm searching for a better way without `Case`.
Does anyone have any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Getting rid of the `CASE` is trivial. But the `(hashtag:HashTag:Featured)` pattern only matches nodes that have *both* labels (`HashTag` AND `Featured`), so `HASHTAG_FEATURED_LABEL` will always be `true`. Also, your use of the [aggregating function](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/functions/aggregating/) `COUNT` may produce unexpected results if you are not careful about the grouping keys in the same `RETURN` clause. Can you modify your question to state clearly what you are trying to do and what results you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can just return the expression, no need for the CASE here :

```
MATCH (:RateableEntity)<-[:TAG]-(hashtag:HashTag:Featured)
WITH hashtag,
'Featured' IN LABELS(hashtag) AS HASHTAG_FEATURED_LABEL
RETURN hashtag.tag As HASHTAG_NAME, 
COUNT(hashtag) as HASHTAG_FREQUENTLY,
HASHTAG_FEATURED_LABEL
ORDER BY HASHTAG_NAME ASC 
SKIP 0
LIMIT 20
```